# Can't upload my app to windows phone store

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps

I ask for forgiveness if this is not the right place to ask this.

Im trying to publish my app to windows phone store. My app is a wp 8.1 app. 
I already paid for the company account and all the tutorials say that I should go to the dashboard, but whenever I tried to enter to the dashboard I got the same screen asking me to choose for the account type again. Is this a bug or what?

I've seen others tutorials and they can do it normally but i can't enter. I can't even find the link of where I reserve the name of my app.

I recive a confirmation from microsoft giving me the welcome.

Is there anything I need to do that Im missing? Why is the dashboard always asking me for account type when I already bought the company account type?

[image: Microsoft confirmation]

Comment: Try deleting all the cookies. Otherwise contact Microsoft directly. Usually there is a support link in the bottom of Microsoft websites.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows Phone and Windows app stores are being unified. If you have been migrated to the unified app store, you should be able to view your dashboard using https://dev.windows.com/overview and submit your app from there or go directly to the submit page on https://dev.windows.com/dashboard/Application/New